# Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Tags: android

when use this code give me this error Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.breakfast);
              ListView lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                try
                {
                    Load_Database();
                } 
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
```

Comment: What are you doing in load_database() method?

Comment: As the error indicates, probably in the Load_Database() method, you don't do anything that would throw a IOException.

Answer (score 0):

The catch block is only needed, if the function `Load_Database()` throws an IOException - since this apparently is not the case (I guess, without seeing the implementation, that `Load_Database()` handles the exception by itself), you should be safe removing the the whole try-catch block and simply call `Load_Database()`

Answer (score 0):

If in your load_database() method you are doing connection creation or any other DB related stuff then change IOException to SQLException.